# Failed to validate oauth signature and token in signing with twitter request

Tags: php, codeigniter, twitter, oauth

i am using login with twitter in **codeigniter**

here is my code:

**Twitterouth.php**

```
function getRequestToken($oauth_callback) {
        $parameters = array();
        $parameters['oauth_callback'] = $oauth_callback;
        $request = $this->oAuthRequest($this->requestTokenURL(), 'POST', $parameters);
        $token = OAuthUtil::parse_parameters($request);

        $this->token = new OAuthConsumer($token['oauth_token'], $token['oauth_token_secret']);

        return $token;
    }
```

---

```
//in function
    $request_token = $this->connection->getRequestToken(base_url('/twitter/callback'));  

            $this->session->set_userdata('request_token', $request_token['oauth_token']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('request_token_secret', $request_token['oauth_token_secret']);
                $url = $this->connection->getAuthorizeURL($request_token);



// in constructor
$this->connection = $this->twitteroauth->create($this->config->item('twitter_consumer_token'), $this->config->item('twitter_consumer_secret'));
```

when i click on the button its goto the controller twitter and function auth and first time

```
$this->connection->http_code
```

its return 401 and on second request its return 200

same as on first request 
return error is

```
  A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: oauth_token

Filename: libraries/Twitteroauth.php

Line Number: 84

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: oauth_token_secret

Filename: libraries/Twitteroauth.php

Line Number: 84

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: oauth_token

Filename: controllers/twitter.php

Line Number: 69

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: oauth_token_secret

Filename: controllers/twitter.php

Line Number: 70

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: oauth_token

Filename: libraries/Twitteroauth.php

Line Number: 96

Array ( [Failed to validate oauth signature and token] => )
```

and on second request its return this:

```
Array ( [oauth_token] => xsSzDXfeiBNKsnwYcGDg9LLGlQST4KhT [oauth_token_secret] => JlkNeaoiLCKGybIENIPtBGi5eqZ09moF [oauth_callback_confirmed] => true )
```

- what is the issue
- am i doing something wrong?
- i am testing this on localhost maybe that's cause issue (but i try this on server but same issue)